# Need help with tables

Tags: tables

This is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\title{\textsc{\fbox{Rappel de trigonométrie}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section})}
    \section{\color{red}Valeurs remarquables et formules élémentaires}

Voici un tableau des valeurs remarquables concernant les fonctions trigonométriques: 

\begin{center}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{6}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule
x       & 0 &\frac{\pi}{6}   &\frac{\pi}{4}   &\frac{\pi}{3}   &\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\ 
\midrule
\cos(x) & 1 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2}     &0            &-1 \\ 
\addlinespace
\sin(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{2}     &\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1            &0  \\ 
\addlinespace
\tan(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&1               &\sqrt3          & /      &0  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{center}
\par
Les fonctions $\cos$ et $\sin$ sont reliées par la formule suivante:
\begin{center}
\fbox{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x) + \sin(x) = 1$}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And I'd like to close the table on the right and left sides could u help me plz?

Comment: Marmot already gave you the better looking table in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498143/reduce-margins-left-and-right You should avoid vertical lines in tabular material.

Comment: Ok ok no problem then ^^ Why should I avoid vertical lines though I thought it’d look cooler as I’m just rewriting my lessons currently

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf This pdf is also on your computer and you can access it with `texdoc booktabs` in a terminal.

Comment: Don't use `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, but rather `\pagestyle{empty}`. Add also `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\maketitle`. Beware that the final formula is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-16pt]{0pt}{38pt}}
\title{\textsc{\fbox{Rappel de trigonométrie}}} 
\date{} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section})} 
\section{\color{red}Valeurs remarquables et formules élémentaires} 
Voici un tableau des valeurs remarquables concernant les fonctions trigonométriques: 
\[
\begin{array}{|>{
\mystrut}l|*{6}{>{\displaystyle}c}|} 
\hline 
x & 0 &\frac{\pi}{6} &\frac{\pi}{4} &\frac{\pi}{3} &\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\ 
\hline 
\cos(x) & 1 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2} &0 &-1 \\ 
\sin(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{2} &\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1 &0 \\  
\tan(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&1 &\sqrt3 & / &0 \\ 
\hline 
\end{array} 
\]

Les fonctions $\cos$ et $\sin$ sont reliées par la formule suivante: 
\[ 
\fbox{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x) = 1$} 
\]
\end{document}
```

With the same strut at the beginning of every row (set with `>{\mystrut}`) all the rows have the same height, but you can also put a different strut at the beginning of a single line for different heights.

No need to use `center` environment if you use `\[...\]`, displaymath is already centered.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The result will be ugly, but if you want to close the table, you can do it like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\title{\textsc{\fbox{Rappel de trigonométrie}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section})}
    \section{\color{red}Valeurs remarquables et formules élémentaires}

Voici un tableau des valeurs remarquables concernant les fonctions trigonométriques: 

\begin{center}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\[
\begin{array}{|@{} l *{6}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}|}
\toprule
x       & 0 &\frac{\pi}{6}   &\frac{\pi}{4}   &\frac{\pi}{3}   &\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\ 
\midrule
\cos(x) & 1 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2}     &0            &-1 \\ 
%\addlinespace
\sin(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{2}     &\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1            &0  \\ 
%\addlinespace
\tan(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&1               &\sqrt3          & /      &0  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{center}
\par
Les fonctions $\cos$ et $\sin$ sont reliées par la formule suivante:
\begin{center}
\fbox{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x) + \sin(x) = 1$}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you removing the horizontal space at the begin and end of the tabular? It makes the result worse than it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

for fun ... with `amsmath`, `amssymb` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section})}

\title{\textsc{\fbox{Rappel de trigonométrie}}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\section{\color{red}Valeurs remarquables et formules élémentaires}
Voici un tableau des valeurs remarquables concernant les fonctions trigonométriques:
\[
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{array}{| l |*{6}{c} |}
    \hline
x       
    & 0 & \dfrac{\pi}{6}    & \dfrac{\pi}{4}    & \dfrac{\pi}{3}    & \dfrac{\pi}{2}    & \pi   \\
    \hline
\cos(x) 
    & 1 & \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt2}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}      & 0                 & -1    \\
\sin(x) 
    & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2}      &\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}  & \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} & 1                 & 0     \\
\tan(x) 
    & 0 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt3} & 1                 & \sqrt3            & \infty            & 0     \\
    \hline
\end{array}
\]

Les fonctions $\cos$ et $\sin$ sont reliées par la formule suivante:
\[
\fbox{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad \cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x) = 1$}
\]
\end{document}
```

For more color solution for your table see the following [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488490/)

[image]